Expected stopping time for Brownian motion conditional on lower barrier being hit first
Suppose we have a Brownian motion $B(t)$, with $B(0) = 0$, and boundaries $a < 0 < b$. Define $\tau_a = \min\{t : B(t) = a\}$ and $\tau_b = \min\{t : B(t) = b\}.$ Conditional on the fact that $a$ was hit first, what is the expected stopping time? I.e., what is $\mathbf{E}[\tau_a | \tau_a < \tau_b]?$
I wanted to use the optional stopping theorem, but it didn't fit, since $\mathbf{E}[B(\tau_a)] = a \neq \mathbf{E}[B(0)].$ Similarly, I couldn't figure out how to use the reflection principle to tackle the problem. I'm aware that without conditioning on the fact that $\tau_a < \tau_b$, the expected stopping time would be infinite, but I think it should be finite when the conditioning is included.
As an aside, I actually need to compute the expectation for a Brownian motion with drift, but even the driftless solution would be greatly helpful!

Optional stopping applied to the martingale $B(t)^2-t$ yields $\mathbf E[\tau_a\wedge\tau_b]=-ab$.
Optional stopping applied to the martingale $B(t)^3-3tB(t)$ yields
$$
a^3{b\over b-a}+b^3{-a\over b-a} = 3a\mathbf E[\tau_a; \tau_a<\tau_b]+3b\mathbf E[\tau_b; \tau_b<\tau_a].
$$
Using $\mathbf E[\tau_a; \tau_a<\tau_b]+\mathbf E[\tau_b; \tau_b<\tau_a]=\mathbf E[\tau_a\wedge\tau_b]$ one can now solve for $\mathbf E[\tau_a; \tau_a<\tau_b]$ in the displayed equation to obtain
$$
\mathbf E[\tau_a; \tau_a<\tau_b]={-ab\over 3}\left[{2b-a\over b-a}\right],
$$
and then
$$
\mathbf E[\tau_b; \tau_b<\tau_a]={-ab\over 3}\left[{b-2a\over b-a}\right],
$$
Finally, because $\mathbf P[\tau_a<\tau_b] ={b\over b-a}$, you have
$$
\mathbf E[\tau_a\,|\,\tau_a<\tau_b]={-a\over 3}(2b-a),
$$
and likewise for $\mathbf E[\tau_b\,|\,\tau_b<\tau_a]$.

This is super helpful! Thank you.
